# Rails 6 Webpack JQuery Yarn - Issue with Bootstrap burger menu not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

So I'm trying to include an external html/css design project to a Rails 6 application using webpack for JS stuff. I've removed Turbolinks (actually turbolinks is still added to the heroku app but we're still with same issue even without it) thinking it might have been easier to get this working properly and then I'd add it back in once working.

I cannot get the bootstrap hamburger button to work (AKA the jQuery doesn't look like it's being called on it) further to that I cannot see any of the animations work similar to how the external templates animations work. I'll add links for comparison. I've added some console logs to double check all js files load in the correct order using the application.js and they seem to do.

I've added a jQuery alert script to the page and it works ok but just none of the other animations of the hamburger menu works. Been racking my brain for a while with this so would appreciate any help. I've added what I've got to heroku to help identify any differences. Thanks a million.

application.js file

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

//import 'bootstrap';
//import '../stylesheets/application'


require("@rails/ujs").start();
// require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("@rails/actiontext");
require("channels");

var jQuery = require("jquery");
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

require("bootstrap");



import flatpickr from "flatpickr"
require("flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css")

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  flatpickr("[date-behaviour='flatpickr]", {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  })
})


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)


require("packs/custom/jquery.min")
require("packs/custom/bootstrap.bundle.min")
require("packs/custom/owl.carousel.min")
require("packs/custom/waypoints.min")
require("packs/custom/jquery.counterup.min")
require("packs/custom/TweenMax.min")
require("packs/custom/wow")
require("packs/custom/jquery.magnific-popup.min")
require("packs/custom/jquery.ajaxchimp.min")
require("packs/custom/swiper.min")
require("packs/custom/typed-2.0.11")
require("packs/custom/vegas.min")
require("packs/custom/jquery.validate.min")
require("packs/custom/bootstrap-select.min")
require("packs/custom/countdown.min")
require("packs/custom/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min")
require("packs/custom/bootstrap-datepicker.min")
require("packs/custom/nouislider.min")
require("packs/custom/isotope")
require("packs/custom/theme")
require("packs/custom/index")
```

environment.js file

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "touristy",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.3-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "expose-loader": "^1.0.3",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "trix": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

In the console you'll see the console alerts on each of the files in applications.js

App is: https://calm-sea-98150.herokuapp.com/

Theme page: [Tripo Theme](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/tripo-html-template-for-travel-tourism-agencies/full_screen_preview/25722332?_ga=2.121000008.1930959347.1610628653-1398152344.1588249070)

Is it an issue with the package.json file - I see bootstrap is above jQuery in the list (do I need to reorder this?)

Also would I be right in saying there might be a conflict by me calling bootstrap with Yarn but also having it as an external js file in the packs/custom folder

I'm pretty new to webpack but think I understand it a little better now after watching [Chris from GoRails explain it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz8d6zPDSrk)

Just not sure where I'm going wrong now with the js files loading? They look like they're loading in the console but they're not doing anything on the page load.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just updating link to working menu bar on the theme i've copied. 

http://layerdrops.com/tripo/?storefront=envato-elements

Comment: If I add the jQuery for the menu item to my console I can get the burger menu to work on click. It seems as though the compiled application.js file is not been loaded after the page is loaded in the browser. Any ideas why this would be the case?

 $('.side-menu__toggler').on('click', function (e) {
      $('.side-menu__block').toggleClass('active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: Just to add to this again. I've added standard bootstrap bar to the homepage - which all works ok. This isolates the issue to the theme js files as none of these seem to work even though they've loaded. I'll update the question with the application.js code. Thanks.